# Adding other fields when call a foreignKey

Tags: mysql, django

I am new in web development and actually I do not know how to ask it but in my main/models.py I have;

```
class First(models.Model):
    two = models.ForeignKey(Two)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

and in my sub/models.py I have;

```
class Two(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

I am using mysql for database and when I login my database and show tables by `select * from firstTable;` I see that;

```
| two_id |name| 
|  1 |  David |
```

When I call ForeignKey(another_model), it automatically show its id. Is it possible to show two_name instead of two_id?

By the way, I hope I explain what I want to do. I really could not explain what I though as one sentence. If you have better explanation for title, please edit my question.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Call it where? Show it where?

Comment: Okay I know I could not explain it very well sorry. When I write "Select * from firstTable", I do not want to see two_id. Instead I want to see two_name. @DanielRoseman

Comment: Why are you writing select statements if you're using Django?

Answer (score 3):

The database is fine like this. You can use a join to show the `name` instead of the `id` in the output of your select statement. This is what Django will do for you (and this is why you want to use Django).

In Django, this will return an instance of your `Two` model:

```
first.two
```

and this way, you can access the `name` of the `Two` instance:

```
first.two.name
```

In a list of several `First` instances, you can output all of the `Two` names like this:

```
First.objects.values('two__name')
```

---

If you really want to look at it in SQL write this:

```
SELECT f.name, t.name FROM firstTable f, twoTable t WHERE f.two_id=t.id;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I know it works. However, I will share view of firstTable and when I share ONLY view of firstTable, can he still see this? That's why I want to add a new column that shows two_name. @Risadinha

Comment: Yes the view can use them just fine. Django will do the join for you and fetch the values. You don't need to normalize the DB for that. That is the whole point of a relational DB, otherwise you are upending its purpose.